# Plugins - is it bad habit to inherit from modified class in order to use protected properties

Tags: magento2, plugin, object, access

If I make plugin it is not neccessary to inherit from class I override. But, sometimes method I change uses properties that has `protected` access and they can't be used by plugin class.

But **if I declare in plugin inheritance after modified class it's possible then to use protected properties.** Is it ok to do it? Or is it better to declare own `__construct()` and inject required classes (I am not sure about difference in states of objects used in plugin and modified class).

**EDIT**
Maybe I wasn't clear anough - I modify `public` method, using (for this question, mostly) `aroundMethod` and for different cases I use `proceed()` or inject custom logic - and for this custom logic I have to use `protected` properties of modified class. And the question is - **should I put inheritance in order to make it possible**

**NOTE**: I don't change any `protected`/`private` - just use it.

Comment: show your code?

Comment: I have the same problem as you.

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154443/m2-plugin-after-method-breaks-checkout-one-page-step-order-modification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Magento 2 plugin is:

> Used to extend or modify a public method’s behavior by applying code
>   before, after, or around that observed method.

**If you're dealing with protected methods or properties then you cannot use plugins.** Making your plugin class extends the original class is definitely not recommended at all.

The list of plugins limitations is available in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

It depends on your needs, but **if you need to change protected properties/methods, you should use preferences instead.**

On top of that you could consider using observers depending on what you want to achieve exactly.

**IMHO, here is the order in which you should choose your way of modifying core classes**:

1. Plugins
2. If you cannot use plugins, observers
3. If you cannot use plugins nor observers, use preferences

Comment: take a look at edit

Answer (score 6):

Plugin should not inherit modified class.

Also it's not recommended to inherit from non-abstract magento classes.